# Cannot grab a string from an HTML 5 table using a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I created an html 5 table with a single column that holds a variety of strings which are YouTube video URLs. I am able to insert strings into the table but the issue is that I am trying to use a JavaScript function to get a link(string) and insert it into my iframe YouTube player. Here is what I have:

Here is my table:

```
Link: <input id="link" type="link" name="link">
<button onClick="appendRow()" > Add Song </button>
<table id = "my_table" table border = "5">
<tr>
   <th>Link</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>http://www.youtube.com/embed/evuSpI2Genw</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is where I call my JavaScript function to insert the URL to the YouTube player:

```
<iframe width="888" height="420"
src="getURL()">
</iframe>
```

Here is my javascript function for grabbing the URL:

```
var counter = 0;
var songURL = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/evuSpI2Genw";
function getNextSong()
{
    if(counter != 0)
    {
        var tbl = document.getElementById('my_table'), // table reference
        songURL = tbl.rows[counter];
        counter++;
        return;
    }
    songURL = tbl.rows[0];
    counter++;
    return;     
}
function getURL()
{
    return songURL;
}
```

Please keep in mind that I am new to both JavaScript and HTML5.

Comment: By the way, is it just me or is the HTML5 table a pain to use. It doesn't seem to be very flexible at all. Wondering if there is a better way to go about this table?

Comment: Aaron wrote: "insert it into my ***iframe*** YouTube player" - I think you'll find that to be the problem. AFAIK, you can consider an iframe something like another tab in the browser, i.e the page that contains it can't get at it's internals. It can set it's 'external' attributes, like src, style, position & size, but can't touch it's DOM. Nah, I think html5 is pretty damned flexible. If you're on a server, I'd be tempted to pass a get or post request to another page, such that the result is the html for the player. I grab with ajax, insert the result into a div..

Comment: Ya, I think HTML5 is very flexible i just believe that the creating this table in HTML doesn't seem to be as flexible. But that's just my opinion. And as far as the internal and external attributes go, you said that externals can be set which really the only attribute I am trying to set is the src attribute which is an external. I will start looking at AJAX now and see what you are talking about. Thanks!

Comment: The <table> element is not relevant to HTML5, in fact it is ancient from the times of pre-CSS webs. HTML5 is VERY flexible and builds on top of the already existing technologies in HTML (and JS, and CSS depending on who you ask what HTML5 covers)

Comment: oh really? I had no idea that was the case. Good to know!

Comment: It also seems you are never calling the `getURL` function

Comment: Also, can I ask, where are you learning HTML? These elements seem very outdated, for what you're trying to do, not that it really matters because you can use whatever element you want, but it will be frustrating for you when you try to add your styling to them versus using other common elements.

For instance you can use <a> tag instead of <input type="link" /> or <button>, and a few <div> tags instead of the ancient <table> element

Comment: @CeaneLamerez the `table` element may be ancient but is still a perfectly valid element for tabular data. A `list` element may be more appropriate here but as there is a table header used here it may be OK to use a table. Its not as if the table is being used for layout.

Comment: @CeaneLamerez And as for the statement _The <table> element is not relevant to HTML5_, **this is just plain wrong**. `Table` should not be used for layout but as I mentioned above it is a perfectaly valid HTML5 entity (look it up) and has its place. How would you dsplay this if there were more columns like artist and title without a table?

Comment: The <table> element is not relevant. In fact it is discouraged by the W3C for use in HTML5! While it may be valid, they do note that it may just be a matter of time before it is deprecated. None of the commonly used attributes on a <table> (cellpaddding, border, cell border, etc) element are valid in HTML5, they have all been deprecated. Therefore, you should rethink your layout by using CSS3 grids, CSS3 flexboxes, or even the display: table attribute, which will give you the same layout as a table, without having to create a table head, table row or table column.

Comment: @CeaneLamerez again just plain wrong. It is part of the html5 spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/tabular-data.html#the-table-element. Please support your claims. I agree the table element should not be used for layout. It should be used for the presentation of tabular data. Which _may_ be the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things you need to consider

`tbl.rows[counter]` will grab the table row as an object, which will contain a collection of cells. You need to get the content of your cell using `tbl.rows[counter].cells[0].innerHTML`

Also you are never setting the `iframe` src. Give it an ID then you can access it via javascript.

Here is rough, and I do mean rough, working sample.

HTML

```
Link: <input id="link" type="url" name="link">
<button onClick="appendRow()" > Add Song </button><button onClick="getNextSong()" > Play Next </button>
<table id = "my_table" table border = "5">
<tr>
   <th>Link</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>http://www.youtube.com/embed/evuSpI2Genw</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<iframe width="888" height="420" id="player"
src="">
</iframe>
```

Javascript

```
var counter = 1;//The Header Row will be row 0
var songURL = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/evuSpI2Genw";
function getNextSong()
{

    var tbl = document.getElementById('my_table'); // table reference
    if(counter != 0)
    {
        songURL = tbl.rows[++counter].cells[0].innerHTML
        document.getElementById('player').src=songURL;
        return;
    }
    songURL = tbl.rows[1].cells[0].innerHTML;
    counter++;
    document.getElementById('player').src=songURL;
    alert(songURL);
    return;  
}

function getURL()
{
    return songURL;
}

function appendRow()
{
    var tbl = document.getElementById('my_table');
    var rowCount = tbl.rows.length;    
    var row = tbl.insertRow(rowCount);
    var cell = row.insertCell(0);
    cell.innerHTML = document.getElementById("link").value;
}
window.onload=function(){

document.getElementById('player').src=getURL();
};
```

I've made other adjustment to your script but it still could do with some tidying up.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/HGKgn/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do, but only changing the src of one iframe on the page.

http://jsbin.com/orinas/2/

Works on IE9+, FF, Chrome, and Safari. Best viewed in Chrome, Safari or IE10.

I created this demo to show you what you could possibly do, while the JS is advanced, there are a lot of core concepts added in that could help you out. Not everything is commented in, because I threw it together quickly, but it is a very good demo that can help you organize your concept.

Notice as well, I do not use the table element =) I use standard elements that you would see on modern web pages today, as well as new CSS3 features.

Instead of having a table full of strings, you should store data like that on JavaScript's side in an Array `[]`. The `links` array in my demo stores all the links that will show up on page load, and afterwards a user can add more links by clicking +Add and inserting a valid Youtube embed URL (something like http://youtube.com/embed/randomString).

I will be updating this answer later on.